# Comparar elementos de un array y asignarle un signo menos si fuese menor que el numero anterior con con lenguaje php

Tags: array, bucles

Intento comparar los elementos de un **array**, para luego verificando que el registro actual es menor que el anterior asignarle un signo "-" al mostrarlos en una tabla

Tengo mi array `$arraydiferencia` que contiene:

```php
Array ( 
    [0] => 9.20 
    [1] => 20.30 
    [2] => 70.30 
    [3] => 40.80 
    [4] => 40.80
)
```

y mi código:

```php
$anterior = null;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arraydiferencia); $i++) {
    if ($anterior != null) {
        if ($arraydiferencia[$i] < $anterior) {
            echo '-'.$arraydiferencia[$i];
        }
    }
    $anterior = $arraydiferencia[$i]; 
}
```

con el código solo logro obtener:

```
-40.80
-40.80
```

que solo son los 2 últimos elementos del array y además no cumplen con lo que requiero obtener, ya que desearía obtener este siguiente resultado en la tabla:

```
9.20
20.30 
70.30
-40.80
40.80
```

cuando la cantidad baja es este caso bajo de 70.30 a 40.80 y es el único caso donde la cifra baja, por tanto le asigno el signo **"-"**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Buen día,

En tu código estas haciendo `echo`  únicamente cuando el valor anterior es mayor que el valor actual y conviertes el valor actual a negativo pero no haces `echo` para el caso contrario (Cuando el valor actual es mayor que el anterior).

Otro consejo: cuando crees variables como `$arraydiferencia` es aconsejable hacerlo de una de las siguientes formas `$arrayDiferencia` (CamelCase, es decir, escribir con mayúscula la primera letra de diferentes palabras) o `$array_diferencia` (Underscore, es decir, poner un guión bajo entre diferentes palabras). Esto ayuda a la lectura rápida de tu código

Modifiqué un poco tu código porque en lo personal cuando uso `if` que solo son de una línea prefiero no escribir los corchetes `{}` para que se vea más compacto

También agregué `"\n` a cada `echo` para que cree un salto de línea

Y si en tu caso el primer valor siempre va a ser positivo podrías iniciar el `for` en `1`

```
<?php
$arrayDiferencia = [ 
    0 => 9.20,
    1 => 20.30,
    2 => 70.30,
    3 => 40.80,
    4 => 40.80,
];

$anterior = null;

for ($i = 1; $i < count($arrayDiferencia); $i++) {
    if ($anterior == null) echo $arrayDiferencia[0] . "\n";
    $anterior = $arrayDiferencia[$i - 1];
    if ($arrayDiferencia[$i] < $anterior) echo '-'.$arrayDiferencia[$i] . "\n";
    else echo $arrayDiferencia[$i] . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: gracias a los dos usuarios que respondieron, sus aportes me sirven de mucho....un abrazo. https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/171630/heytalepazguato

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esto:

```php
<?php

$arraydiferencia = [
    9.20,
    20.30,
    70.30,
    40.80,
    40.80
];

$anterior = null;
$salida = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arraydiferencia); $i++) {
    if ($anterior != null) {
        if ($arraydiferencia[$i] < $anterior) {
            $salida[] = '-'.$arraydiferencia[$i];
        } else {
            $salida[] = $arraydiferencia[$i];
        }
    } else {
        $salida[] = $arraydiferencia[$i];
    }
    $anterior = $arraydiferencia[$i];
}
print_r($salida);
```

El resultado almacenado en `$salida` es un **array** con estos valores:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9.2
    [1] => 20.3
    [2] => 70.3
    [3] => -40.8
    [4] => 40.8
)
```

**Explicación:**

Como pides que la salida contenga todos los datos, lo que tendrias que haber realizado desde el principio es almacenar el valor inicial, o el modificado con el símbolo `-` delante, en cada iteración del bucle en una *variable* de **array**, tal como he realizado en esta respuesta, usando la variable `$salida` que primero he inicializado antes del bucle.

O bien, si lo que quieres no es almacenarlo en una variable, sino mostrarlo en la salida, sencillamente cambia todos los `$salida[] =` por `echo`.

---

**Edición:**

Si te va lo friki y quieres poner todo este código en una linea con [operadores ternarios](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) y haciendo el `echo` directamente puedes hacerlo así:

```php
$arrayDiferencia = [ 
    0 => 9.20,
    1 => 20.30,
    2 => 70.30,
    3 => 40.80,
    4 => 40.80,
];

$anterior = null;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arraydiferencia); $i++) {
    echo ($anterior != null) ? ($arraydiferencia[$i] < $anterior) ? '-'.$arraydiferencia[$i]."\n" : $arraydiferencia[$i]."\n" : $arraydiferencia[$i]."\n";
    $anterior = $arraydiferencia[$i];
}
```

Esto te devolverá:

```
9.2
20.3
70.3
-40.8
40.8
```

Aunque desde mi punto de vista se entiende mucho peor.